# The quickest way to reduce an isolated system's temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, temperature, cooling

If you are in an isolated room, having an air conditioner and a ceiling fan. What is the quickest way to cool the room.
Using only the air conditioner or both of them?

Answer (score 1):

If the room is isolated (can't exchange heat with the rest of the universe) then the air conditioner must be "part of the room" and only able to draw in air from the room and expel air to the room.  Also, the power source for the air conditioner and fan must be inside the room, otherwise the system isn't isolated.  So let's say we have a battery to operate them.

The air conditioner takes in warm air and expels cold air, but the thermal energy removed from the air doesn't disappear.  The air conditioner must expel thermal energy to somewhere.  Energy from the battery is used to operate the air conditioner.  But this energy also can't disappear.  It gets transformed into thermal energy which must also be expelled from the air conditioner.  If the air conditioner can't expel this thermal energy outside the room (because the system is isolated) then it is all expelled back into the room.  So the net effect of running the air conditioner is to convert chemical energy in the battery into thermal energy in the room.  The air conditioner heats up the room.  Ditto for the fan.

Of course, if one of the walls can move (the room is a large piston) you could adiabatically expand the air in the room to cool it.  Unfortunately, this would be rather uncomfortable for anyone in the room.

Comment: Okay suppose that the whole system is isolated. However, the air conditioner can expel heat outside.

Comment: If the air conditioner can expel heat outside then the system isn't isolated.  In the context of energy, isolated means "no energy enters or leaves the system".  Back to the original question, if the system **isn't** isolated (because the air conditioner expels heat outside the room), the air conditioner will cool it faster than the fan, since the fan doesn't cool it at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's no question that the *quickest* way to cool *all* the air in the room is by using the fan to circulate hot air into the air conditioner.  But in a thermodynamically isolated room, the air conditioner dumps hot air, as well as cold air, into the room.  It's unwise and energy inefficient to use an air conditioner in a truly isolated room.  You need to direct the hot air from the air conditioner's condensing coil out of the room, otherwise the electric motor and friction in the air conditioner will stop cooling the room, and will heat it up.

(In the event that this is not a theoretical question about a truly thermodynamically isolated room, and you are considering using a portable air conditioner, here are some warnings to consider: http://homeenergypros.lbl.gov/profiles/blogs/warnings-about-portable-air-conditioners.)

Answer (score 0):

Compared with the other folks here **I am not an expert**, but since I am struggling with a similar problem I will share what I understood until now, hoping it can help.

The **first law** states that energy cannot be created or destroyed in an isolated system. So the only possibility is to "transform" it, and for doing so you have basically two ways: **heat transfer** or **work transfer**. Since in an isolated system you can not transfer heat outside the system, you can only go for work transfer. Thus you need to convert the thermal energy of the fluid (air) inside the room in another form of energy, in order to reduce its temperature.

Unfortunately the **second law** states: the entropy of any isolated system always increases. This sets a **limit to the amount of heat that can be turned into work**. Efficiency of heat engines is a direct consequence. The maximum amount of work you can obtain from heat is given by the Carnot efficiency, which is lower than 100% meaning you cannot turn all the thermal energy into work.

In your situation **neither an air conditioner nor a ceiling fan would help**. Maybe the fan could lower a bit the human perceived apparent temperature, but still the temperature would remain the same.

I would suggest, but not being an expert maybe I am talking about something impossibile to implement, to think about a way to **reduce the temperature of the fluid inside the system by converting a part of its thermal energy into work**, reducing the overall temperature of the fluid. In any case, being your system isolated the total amount of energy inside it will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the air conditioner by itself, the cooler air will tend to be close to the air conditioner, the warmer air farther away.  The heat exchange will work better if the air around the condenser coils is warm.  So the best thing to do is to have a fan and situate it to move the cool air away from the AC, and the warm air towards it.